# Restoring KeyListener of EditText in android after setting it to null loses Input Type options

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-inputtype

I need to make `EditText` read-only after taking input from user once. I am setting its `KeyListener` to null after saving its `KeyListener` object in a variable using `getKeyListener()`. But the `InputType` information (eg: Email, URI etc) is lost after I restore the KeyListener object back using `setKeyListener()`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText et;
KeyListener kl;
Button b;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
    et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
    kl = et.getKeyListener();

    et.setKeyListener(null);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("ST","changed");                              
            et.setKeyListener(kl);              
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here I have set `InputType` to `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS` but on restoring the `KeyListener`, Soft Keyboard is of type `TPYE_CLASS_TEXT` and not Email.

How can I get the previous InputType state of `EditText` after setting its `KeyListener` to null?

**EDIT**
I added a log after `et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS)` to get values of InputType and I get the following :

```
D/ST(16190): et.getInputType() : 33, et.getKeyListener().getInputType() : 1
```

And after restoring the `KeyListener` I get the follwing result:

```
D/ST(16190): et.getInputType() : 1 et.getKeyListener().getInputType() : 1
```

Shouldn't they be same?

On which value (`et.getInputType()` or `et.getKeyListener().getInputType()`) does the type of soft keyboard dispatched depend upon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

more appropriate:

```
et.setEnabled(false);
```

otherwise

```
et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_AD‌​DRESS);
```

after you reset the keylistener

Comment: `et.setEnabled(false)` causes the text to be greyed out. I want the text to look like a `TextView`.

Comment: If you want it to look like a `TextView` why not hide the `EditText` and show a `TextView` once the user input has been taken...

Comment: I need to periodically switch between read-only and edit mode. Using two Views seems weird, since `EditText` is just a thin wrapper around `TextView`.

Comment: ya if you really need it to look like a TextView just place them on top of each other and show/hide as needed

Comment: @Shooky Actually I am working with an existing piece of code. So have to understand whats wrong here before changing stuff.

Comment: the docs basically state that setting the KeyListener to null as mysterious affects on the properties of the EditText,  if you must retain this code why not just reset the inputType after you reassign the old KeyListener? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setKeyListener(android.text.method.KeyListener)

Comment: @Shooky The documentatio states that "This (key listener) can be null to disallow user input." What do you mean by reset the inputType?

Comment: Yes that method is documented,  not preferred but exceptable.  Just call    et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS); after you reset the keylistener

Comment: @Shooky Calling `setInputType` after restoring `KeyListener` works, but I am not sure why setting the keyListener to `null` changes value returned by `et.getInputType()`. Could you please post the above comment as answer so that I can mark it as answer.

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect your request.  In the docs link I posted it does explicitly state "Calling this method will replace the current content type of the text view with the content type returned by the key listener." (which in your case is null)

Answer (score 1):

```
fathersNameET.setKeyListener(new BaseKeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public int getInputType() {
                        return 1;
                    }
                });
```

fathersNameET is your editText instance name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following should be able to stop a user typing into it after it is called

```
et.setFocusable(false);
```